# how to dynamically add $scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my HTML:

```
...
<table class="tickerTable">
<thead>
  <th>Symbol</th>
  <th>Accts</th>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="ticker in tickers">
  <tr ng-click="showTrades(ticker)">
<td >{{ticker.Ticker}}</td>
<td>{{ticker.TradeCount}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="currentItem == ticker">
<td colspan="2">{{trades}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the controller:

```
$scope.showTrades = function(ticker){
  $scope.trades = {};
  $scope.currentItem = ticker;
  $scope.trades = "this is the result of a rest call using the params from $scope.ticker";
};
```

the table is populated with many rows. for each row i add a blank row that is hidden by default.

when the row is clicked the hidden row displays dynamically generated content that is returned from a rest call made with the params of that particular table row's "ticker" object. the result is injected into $scope.trades and displayed in the now visible TR.

The problem: {{trades}} is being populated in every hidden row along with the revealed row. I only want it to load in the revealed row.

## solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/qFZyeuIbt6z5dYEFFHzr?p=preview

Comment: You cannot add a controller to `$scope`. A controller should be attached to the object returned by `angular.module`

Comment: Its better you provide a plunk for this.

Comment: i do not understand what that means

Comment: Plunk is a online editor where you can place your code and share.. http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: R u trying to add a new controller to $scope?

Comment: You should do this on the server.  only fetch the rows you want to display.

Comment: What you want as a output. explain

Comment: the output is correct, but i only want {{trades}} populated in the row being referenced (shown). the dataset is quite large. I cannot afford to have it load in every instance of {{trades}} in the hidden rows

Comment: why not use ng-if: <td ng-if="currentItem == ticker" colspan="2">{{trades}}</td> ?

Comment: same issue once it evaluates to TRUE every instance of {{trades}} is populated even if they are hidden

Comment: Use atleast version 1.1.5 for `ng-if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qFZyeuIbt6z5dYEFFHzr?p=preview) you are using ng-if. 
There is a bug relatead to ng-if in tables [#3104](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3104) which will cause problems for you. Maybe you can use ng-show instead as you did in the posted HTML?

Next you may add the trades to the containing ticker. So you display the trades belonging to the current ticker. Then only the selected ticker row will have trades.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='portfolio'>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<table ng-controller = "TickerListCtrl">
    <thead>
      <th>Symbol</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="ticker in tickers">
      <tr ng-click="showTrades(ticker)">
          <td>{{ticker.Ticker}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
          <td ng-show="currentItem == ticker" colspan="2">{{ticker.trades}}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

$scope.showTrades = function(ticker){
   ticker.trades = "this is trades for ticker: " + ticker.Ticker;
   $scope.currentItem = ticker;   
};
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jxv6gnF5izDSOzHQWFVZ?p=preview) is a fork of your plnkr with the described changes.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for!! i knew it was simple, i just couldn't work it out. thank you!!

Comment: Is there a simple way to unset the previous ticker.trades if another row is selected, so the DOM isn't filling up with more and more hidden data each time?

Comment: i modified the plunker to show my solution and I updated the post

Comment: if you save the ticker in $scope.currentItem as you did in your first version, then you could check it and unset the trades in your showTrades function. $scope.showTrades = function(ticker){ if ($scope.currentItem){ $scope.currentItem.trades = null; }. See my plnkr fork for updates.

Comment: i built a hybrid of this. you can see it in the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qFZyeuIbt6z5dYEFFHzr?p=preview